# Beamer: vertically centered slide content

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment

I am trying to make a slideshow for a quiz. In between rounds, I want to put a blank slide with just the title of that round, vertically centered. The title slide should also be vertically centered.

Because the default slides (questions) show the round and question number as a footline, I defined a blank slide command:

```
% Frame without footline.
\newcommand{\blankframe}[1]{
    {%
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{center}
            #1
        \end{center}
    \end{frame}
    }
}
```

I use this to create a title slide as follows:

```
\blankframe{
  {\huge My Quiz Title}
  \vfill
  {\scriptsize 2014}
}
```

and a new round:

```
\newcommand{\round}[2]{
    \stepcounter{roundCounter}
    \stepcounter{questionCounter}
    \renewcommand{\currentRoundName}{#1}
    \renewcommand{\currentRoundQuestions}{#2}
    \blankframe{
        {\huge #1}
    }
}
```

But the result is not entirely vertically centered, it's slightly tilted towards the top:
[image: Example output]

Does anybody know what is going on here? Could it be because of the empty frametitle, and how could I fix that?

Thanks in advance!

Here is a full working example:

```
\documentclass[xelatex]{beamer}

\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setbeamerfont{question}{size*={14}{1.4em}}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\newcounter{roundCounter}
\newcounter{questionCounter}[roundCounter]

\newcommand{\currentRoundName}{}
\newcommand{\currentRoundQuestions}{0}

% Start a new round with 2 arguments:
%  #1    Round name
%  #2    Number of questions in this round. 
\newcommand{\round}[2]{
    \stepcounter{roundCounter}
    \stepcounter{questionCounter}
    \renewcommand{\currentRoundName}{#1}
    \renewcommand{\currentRoundQuestions}{#2}
    \blankframe{
        {\huge #1}
    }
}

% Frame without footline.
\newcommand{\blankframe}[1]{
    {%
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{center}
            #1
        \end{center}
    \end{frame}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\blankframe{
  {\huge My Quiz Title}
  \vfill
  {\scriptsize 2014}
}

\round{Warm-up round}{10}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps adding a strategically placed `\vfill`, as in `\blankframe{
  {\vfill\huge My Quiz Title}
  \vfill
  {\scriptsize 2014}
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the titleframe `\vfill` I mention, in my comment, better centering can also be achieved with more `\vfill`s in the definition of `\blankframe`.

```
\documentclass[xelatex]{beamer}

\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setbeamerfont{question}{size*={14}{1.4em}}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\newcounter{roundCounter}
\newcounter{questionCounter}[roundCounter]

\newcommand{\currentRoundName}{}
\newcommand{\currentRoundQuestions}{0}

% Start a new round with 2 arguments:
%  #1    Round name
%  #2    Number of questions in this round. 
\newcommand{\round}[2]{
    \stepcounter{roundCounter}
    \stepcounter{questionCounter}
    \renewcommand{\currentRoundName}{#1}
    \renewcommand{\currentRoundQuestions}{#2}
    \blankframe{
        {\huge #1}
    }
}

% Frame without footline.
\newcommand{\blankframe}[1]{
    {%
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
    \begin{frame}
        \vfill\vfill\centering#1\vfill\vfill
    \end{frame}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\blankframe{
  {\vfill\huge My Quiz Title}\vfill
  {\scriptsize 2014}
}

\round{Warm-up round}{10}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: presumably just looks more centred as 3/7 is a better approximation to 1/2 than the original 1/3 is. (there is one `\vfill` from the frame and you have 3 above and 3 below.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes.

Comment: removing the extra fill, or using filll glue would be easier then:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I know you are suggesting something simple, but I'm confused.  If I replace `\vfill\vfill\centering#1\vfill\vfill` with `\vfill\vfill\centering#1\vfill`, I would call that an improvement.  But if I replace it with `\vfill\centering#1`, it is not centered.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I suppose I could try running it, I was just looking at the images as posted:-)